# @Version column gets updated even though persist was never called

Tags: java, database, jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0

I've a database with two tables (more actually, but that shouldn't matter in this case). One of the two has a foreign key reference to the other. These could be the mappings:

```
@Entity @Table public class A {
   @Id public String id;
   @Version public int version;
   @OneToMany(targetEntity = B.class,
              mappedBy = "a",
              cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   public Collection<B> bs;

   ...
}

@Entity @Table public class B {
   @Id public String id;
   @Version public int version;
   @ManyToOne(targetEntity = A.class,
              cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   public A a;

   ...
}
```

I've an intermediate data structure which holds information on the relationship between `A` and `B` which I iterate over before persisting my data inside an active transaction, checking if an `A` or `B` already exists in the database or not using `EntityManager.find(Class<T>, Object)`:

```
// get an entity manager and begin transaction
for (C c : cs) {
    A a = em.find(A.class, c.getAId()); // an `A` doesn't exist in the database
    if (null == a) {                    // on first iteration so a new one will
        a = new A();                    // be created
        a.id = c.getAId();              // however in a 100 `C` there are 4-5
    }                                   // unique `A` exists

    B b = em.find(B.class, c.getBId()); // a `B` generally doesn't exist in
    if (null == b) {                    // the database, but the opposite
        b = new B();                    // could happen often
        b.id = c.getBId();
        b.a = a;
        a.bs.add(b);
    }       

    if (!em.contains(b))                // if a `B` was found in the database
      em.persist(b);                    // persist won't execute here
}
// commit transaction
```

This works great: new data gets persisted, already existing stuff don't.

*However!* The version column in my database ***always*** gets updated no matter what happens in the for-each loop. I've taken a set of sample data, persisted it in my empty tables (versions was at 0); I've taken this same set of sample data and persisted it again (`EntityManager.persist(Object)` never got called) and the version fields (in `A`) got updated, but I can't imagine why.

I'm aware the fact that even though `EntityManager.persist(Object)` never got called my persistence provider (Hibernate) generated the update statements to increment the version column.

The questions: Why? How can I prevent this? What should I change in my method of persisting my data in order to avoid this? Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I knocked your code into runnable shape - https://gist.github.com/914504 - and ran it with OpenJPA 2.0.1 (i renamed the classes because, believe it or not, OpenJPA chokes on a class called 'B'!). The version column does not get incremented with repeated runs. What provider are you using? Can you run this little app with your provider and see what happens?

Comment: `I can't reproduce this.` Since then me neither. Your code works flawlessly... I had to modify my database layout a bit, added code there, stripped some there... and it's gone. :/ I had a hunch what was the problem tho'. My tables didn't use unique columns as ids, but auto-generated keys. Because of this I couldn't use `EntityManager.find(Object)`, I had to write queries on the unique fields. And I think after a successful query Hibernate (my provider) incremented the queried entity's version. I couldn't think else.

Comment: Such is the life of the programmer! I would say, though, that when you're posting a cut-down example, it is worth checking that it really does reproduce the problem - because if it doesn't, you've already taken a big step towards a solution. And of course, anyone else working from your example won't be able to help you!

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but I just couldn't possibly believe that executing a query increments the version field... maybe it isn't.  :) I'm not sure yet. I'll check into it when I have the time and update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that's what's happening here is that you have the [lock mode](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html) set to OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT. If you were to set it to plain OPTIMISTIC, then you would not see the update. The javadoc explanation of the behaviour is precise but rather dense; there is also a [blog post](http://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_2_0_concurrency_and) which might help.

I think the point of OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT is that it protects consistency in the database. Imagine you had two As, a1 and a2, each with a single B. Two threads load both of them. Thread 1 sets a1 to have two Bs, and a2 to have a single B (the status quo). Thread 2 sets a1 to have one B (the status quo) and a2 to have two Bs. Thread 1 commits before thread 2. With OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT, thread 2 will get an exception, because the objects have already been modified by thread 1. With OPTIMISTIC, thread 2 would succeed, because each thread would only bump the version on the object it was adding a B to. If thread 2 succeeds, the database now represents a state that neither of the threads committed - a1 and a2 both have two Bs.

Now, it might be that this inconsistency - a sort of implicit merging of states - is acceptable, and indeed exactly what you want. But JPA can't assume that in general, so OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT is available. I don't know if it's the default (i can't find any documentation saying so, but it would be sensible), or if you're setting it explicitly somewhere else.

As for solutions, in the case where nothing at all is modified, you could simply not commit the session. If you are dealing with cases where some objects are modified and some not, you could process each A object in its own session. Or you could just use OPTIMISTIC locking. If i'm right, that is!

Comment: I've tried using `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC` in `EntityManager.find(...)` to no avail. The versions got updated. However my main problem is, that if I *do not change the state* of my rows and *do not persist* anything, just do a commit the versions on my rows gets updated nonetheless. `As for solutions, in the case where nothing at all is modified, you could simply not commit the session.` Yeah, this wouldn't work, because usually there are rows created every time, I cannot dismiss those. You're reasoning on optimistic locking is right on, but this isn't really my problem.

Comment: After quite a while I've reviewed my question and also your answer. I couldn't reproduce the problem I had faced back then for the love of my life. Using explicitly `EntityManager.find(..., LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)` reproduces the problem however, but I don't know how did I managed to _use_ it (because I didn't use no locking, never, no one can prove it otherwise! :). One possibility is that the version of Hibernate I've used (maybe a beta release, I'm not sure), used _that_ as default ... Anyway, your answer is very good, so I'm accepting it! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
 B b = em.find(B.class, c.getBId()); // a `B` generally doesn't exist in      
 if (null == a) {
```

I suppose you made a small mistake while posting this two lines of code, the variable in if condition should be  b instead of a. If this is the case below line causes update of the version field.

```
 a.bs.add(b);
```

Comment: Indeed `null == a` is `null == b`, thanks. However if `b` is found in the persistence context then `a.bs.add(b)` never gets executed, thus the version field corresponding to `a` *shouldn't* get updated (in my book at least).

Comment: well, you were correct when b is found , a is not updated.. But when b could not be found, then a new B entity is created and , it is associated with found a.

Comment: Exactly, but the problem is *the version column in my database **always** gets updated no matter what happens*, even when `b` is found and `EntityManager.persist(Object)` is never called. I want to know why is this happens and what can I do about it.